# RAID (mdadm) - What happens if drives are mismatched in size?

Tags: raid, mdadm

Question 1 - Before you answer with "it just takes the smaller disk", hear me out quick. My 3TB WD Reds come out to be 3001 GB in size. Let's say I set up a mirror via mdadm for sdb1 and sdc1 which span 100% of the drive. But suddenly, one of the drives fail. The replacement is a 3TB, weighing in at 3000 GB. What happens when I put in a drive that is smaller than the one currently existent on the array? I know with a new array using 3000 vs 3001, it would build the array to be 3000. But like I said, what about a current array @ 3001 and I add a smaller drive? Does it re-structure itself during the rebuild to be 3000 GB in size?

Question 2 - In the event that I can't add a 3000 GB to the array with an existing 3001 GB and it simply downsize to 3000... can I resize the 3001 down a bit?

Question 3 - Or, a better idea. What if I downsize my 3TB drive to be 2999 GB. That way whether the drive is short by 1 MB, 1 byte, 10 KB, doesn't matter, it'll always pick up the "smaller" drive @ 2999 GB.

Answer (score 32):

I came across this answer by mistake, but in case anyone is curious, here's an answer supported by experiments.

## The Short Version

**Bonus Question: can I create an `md(4)` RAID array out of block devices of unequal size?** Yes, but the RAID array will have the size of the *smallest* block device (plus some overheads for its own housekeeping). If device sizes aren't within 1% of each other, you get a warning.

**Question 1: can I add to an existing `md(4)` RAID array a device smaller than the smallest current member?** Nope, sorry. `mdadm` will flat out refuse to do that to protect your data.

**Question 2: can you resize an existing md array?** Yes (read the `mdadm` manpge!), but it may not be worth the effort. You'll have to back everything up, then resize the contents of the RAID device, then resize the device itself — all of this is quite prone to errors, miscalculations, and other things that'll cost you your data (painful experience talking).

It's not worth the risk and effort. If you have a new, blank disk, here's how to resize it and also keep between one and two copies of all your data intact at all times (assuming you have 2-disk RAID1):

1. Create a new `md(4)` array on it (with one disk missing).
2. Recreate the structure of the array contents (Crypto, LVM, partitions tables, any combination thereof, whatever floats your boat).
3. Copy the data from the existing disk to the new one.
4. Reboot, using the new disk.
5. Wipe the old disk's partition table (or zero the `md(4)` superblock). If necessary, create the required partitions to match the scheme on he new disk.
6. Add the old disk to the new array.
7. Wait for the array members to sync. Have some coffee. Fly to Latin America and pick your own coffee beans, for that matter. :) (If you live *in* Latin America, fly to Africa instead).

Note: yes, this is the same technique 0xC0000022L described in his answer.

**Question 3.** What if the drive is 1G short? :) Don't worry about it. Chances are your replacement drive will be bigger. In fact, with a strategy like above it *pays* to get cheaper larger drives whenever one fails (or for a cheaper upgrade). You can get a progressive upgrade.

## Experimental Proof

### Experimental Setup

First, let's fake some block devices. We'll use `/tmp/sdx` and `/tmp/sdy` (each 100M), and `/tmp/sdz` (99M).

```bsh
cd /tmp
dd if=/dev/zero of=sdx bs=1M count=100
sudo losetup -f sdx
dd if=/dev/zero of=sdy bs=1M count=100
sudo losetup -f sdy
dd if=/dev/zero of=sdz bs=1M count=99  # Here's a smaller one!
sudo losetup -f sdz
```

This sets up three files as three loopback block devices: `/dev/loop0`, `/dev/loop1` and `/dev/loop2`, mapping to `sdx`, `sdy` and `sdz` respectively. Let's check the sizes:

```
sudo grep loop[012] /proc/partitions
   7        0     102400 loop0
   7        1     102400 loop1
   7        2     101376 loop2
```

As expected, we have two loop devices of exactly 100M (102400 KiB = 100 MiB) and one of 99M (exactly 99×1024 1K blocks).

### Making a RAID Array out of Identically-Sized Devices

Here goes:

```
sudo mdadm  --create -e 1.2 -n 2 -l 1 /dev/md100 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
mdadm: array /dev/md100 started.
```

Check the size:

```
sudo grep md100 /proc/partitions
   9      100     102272 md100
```

This is **precicely** what we expect: one look at the mdadm manual reminds us that version 1.2 metadata take up 128K: 128 + 102272 = 102400. Now let's destroy it in preparation for the second experiment.

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md100
sudo mdadm --misc --zero-superblock /dev/loop0
sudo mdadm --misc --zero-superblock /dev/loop1
```

### Making a RAID Array out of Unequally Sized Devices

This time we'll use the small block device.

```
sudo mdadm  --create -e 1.2 -n 2 -l 1 /dev/md100 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop2
mdadm: largest drive (/dev/loop0) exceeds size (101248K) by more than 1%
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: array /dev/md100 started.
```

Well, we got warned, but the array was made. Let's check the size:

```
sudo grep md100 /proc/partitions
   9      100     101248 md100
```

What we get here is 101,248 blocks. 101248 + 128 = 101376 = 99 × 1024. The usable space is that of the smallest device (plus the 128K RAID metadata). Let's bring it all down again for our last experiment:

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md100
sudo mdadm --misc --zero-superblock /dev/loop0
sudo mdadm --misc --zero-superblock /dev/loop2
```

### And Finally: Adding a smaller Device to a Running Array

First, let's make a RAID1 array with just one of the 100M disks. The array will be degraded, but we don't really care. We just want a **started** array. The `missing` keywords is a placeholder that says ‘I don't have a device for you yet, start he array now and I'll add one later’.

```
sudo mdadm  --create -e 1.2 -n 2 -l 1 /dev/md100 /dev/loop0 missing
```

Again, let's check the size:

```
sudo grep md100 /proc/partitions
   9      100     102272 md100
```

Sure enough, it's 128K short of 102400 blocks. Adding the smaller disk:

```
sudo mdadm  --add /dev/md100 /dev/loop2
mdadm: /dev/loop2 not large enough to join array
```

Boom! It won't let us, and the error is very clear.

Comment: Synology Hybrid RAID (SHR) solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to set up `mdX` devices. The method would be to use `gdisk` (or `sgdisk` if you prefer the command-line only version) to partition this as GPT. If you want to boot from the array create a "BIOS Boot Partition", type code `ef02`. This is only necessary if you want to boot off this array, otherwise no need to care. Then, create a partition the same size or smaller than the smallest disk to be added to the array. Last but not least, copy the GPT data over to the other disk (expert menu in `gdisk`, using `x`, and then `u` and specify the target device). This is a destructive process.

It should be possible - if the file system allows for it - to resize an existing partition to something smaller and then use the same method to copy the GPT data. However, this gets you into a bit of a kerfuffle. Because now you have two disks, but still no `mdX` device. One of them has to be prepared as `mdX`, either partition-wise (which I implied above) or disk-wise) and then the data must be moved from the existing disk to that.

So:

1. big disk (`/dev/sda`) contains data, data is smaller than 3001 GB, partitions are not
2. smaller disk `/dev/sdb` gets added to the system
3. you partition `/dev/sdb` with `gdisk`
4. you create an array from each respective partition (`mdadm -C /dev/md2 -l 1 -n 1 /dev/sdb2`)
5. you create file systems on the new arrays
6. you copy all data over, making sure that your system will be prepared to run off a GPT disk and making GRUB2 understand the implications (see below)
7. you copy the GPT partitioning data over from `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/sda`
8. you add the "raw" partitions from `/dev/sda` into the existing arrays
9. you wait for `/proc/mdstat` to show you that the synching is done

If you followed all steps you should now be able to boot into the new system off the mdX arrays. However, keep a rescue CD or a PXE boot option handy, just in case.

---

GRUB2 will not be able to recognize the setup off hand. So you need some "magic". Here's a one-liner:

```
for i in /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-*; do DEV=$(readlink $i); echo "(${DEV##*/}) $i"; done|sort|tee /boot/grub/devicemap
```

Or let's be more verbose:

```
for i in /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-*
do
  DEV=$(readlink $i)
  echo "(${DEV##*/}) $i"
done|sort|sudo tee /boot/grub/devicemap
```

This creates (or overwrites) the default `/boot/grub/devicemap` with one that tells GRUB2 where to find each respective disk. The result would be something like this list:

```
(md0) /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-...
(md2) /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-...
(md3) /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-...
(md4) /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-...
```

If you use legacy GRUB, you also need to create the "BIOS Boot Partition" with meta-data version 0.9, using `mdadm -e 0 ...` and the process will differ. I haven't done that, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This array is actually just for raw storage on my server so it won't be handling booting or anything like that. I was just concerned about mixing and matching different size hard drives later in the game. I mean, what WOULD happen if I have sdb1 @ 3001 GB and sdc1 @ 3001 GB, but sdc1 dies and the replacement is 3000 GB? Does sdb1 downsize to 3000? Does the array @ /dev/md0 downsize to 3000 GB? The more I think about it, the more it makes sense to leave room at the end, such as the 2999 example above - that way it should remove that headache. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Actually, assuming RAID level 1 here, `mdadm` would refuse to build the array in the first place if it's incompatible. In RAID 5 you'd need more disks eventually and in RAID 0 you wouldn't care about it, which is why I assumed RAID 1. So yes, it makes sense to leave room.

Comment: I don't mean to beat the horse, but I'm a little unsure about the "incompatible" statement you made. What would be incompatible? Were you referencing the size differences in terms of 3000 GB vs 3001 GB in my example? Either way, I just ran my array with each partition being 2999 GB, even though each disk was 3001 GB. This should just remove any headaches that come down the line in the event I can't get identical replacement drives. Appreciate your insight!

Comment: @JaSauders: I *think* one GiB more or less would already be incompatible. But quite frankly I don't know where the limit is. I know, however, that slight variations in size will be tolerated. For everything else you have to migrate in a way similar to what I outlined.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: `mdadm` tolerates an arbitrary 1% of size difference in array members.